# How to read XML file in Angular 4, 5, 6 and get output as String?

Tags: xml, angular6

I am using an angular 6 and I want to read XML file.

I have a sample file sample.xml to my local machine.

```
 <mail>
    <to>abc@gmail.com</to>
    <from>xyz@gmail.com</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body> Party this week !</body>
 </mail>
```

and I want to chose file and fetch all file data as String. 
ex. same file as String: `<mail><to>abc@gmail.com</to><from>xyz@gmail.com</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body> Party this week !</body></mail>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert xml file to String in Angular 4, 5, 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867683/how-to-convert-xml-file-to-string-in-angular-4-5-6)

Comment: @Epistaxis , Yes it's Duplicate, I am expected that some one will mark duplicate answer not question. Do you have answer?